# Upgrade Codeigniter 1.7.1 to 3.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, upgrade

I need upgrade my website codeigniter to `V 3.6` from  `V 1.7.1`, but I don't know where I can find the `version 1.7.2` because that isn't in the repository.

I use this user guide (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) for  upgrade but this is absolutely necessary to do all the steps `1.7.1 to 1.7.2, 1.7.2 to 2.0,...` or can I do directly from `version 1.7.1` to the `last version 3.6`?

Thanks!

Comment: You could upgrade directly to any version you'd like as of now, however keep in mind that the framework changed it's core functions so you will need to deal with some errors that will occure. What's most likely to break would be login scripts, database connections.

Comment: No no no you do not have to upgrade through each version. There are actually not that many changes. Basically you are going to upper case your controller and model file names, and do a search and replace to change how the controller and models are called. What I would suggest is really work through - not just read - the tutorial in the CI manual. Then take one part of your 1.7.2 app and upgrade it to CI 3. That should give you a good view on what you will need to do. But again its mostly going to be search/replace so use a good code editor.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, as [cartalot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004319/cartalot) said, you don't need to upgrade through each version, one by one. Just read all the [instructions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) to upgrade between your version and the target one, and build a list of things to do, then you can execute that list on one go. Here are some of the things that I added to my list when upgrading from 1.7.2 to 3.1.3.

- Add `return parent::__get($prop);` to your **_get** magic methods (if you have them).
- Replace `$this->validation->error_string` with `validation_errors()`
- Replace in views `$this->validation->field_name` with `set_value(‘field_name’)` and `set_select()`, etc.. And add the value to be used to pre-populate each field. But take in account that `set_value()` does not work if you don’t run `form_validation->run()` first.
- When retrieving data: Replace `$this->validation->field_name` and `$this->form_validation->field_name` with `$this->input->post(‘field_name’)`
- When setting data: Replace `$this->form_validation->field_name` with `$this->form_validation->set_data($data);`
- Take in account that `set_data($other_data)` overwrites the content of `$_POST`, so you need to merge `$other_data` and `$_POST`.

Good luck, and just power through it!.